# Android Vuforia Cloud Recognation Display BookOverlay after back from webView

Tags: android, vuforia

I have downloaded the Cloud Recognition Sample from Vuforia samples and tried and the Book cover and it worked. When we click on Book Overlay webview opens and shows book details on website but when we back (press android back) from webview application show camera with scanning.

I want application should display same BookOverlay after back from webview without scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get you answer looking for method setScanningMode in BooksRenderer.java